# Adding option group to option list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, lotus-domino

I have the following HTML code (note no closing tags on `<\option>`) generated by Lotus Domino.

```
<select name="Fault" class="textbox">
<option>Single Light Out
<option>Light Dim
<option>Light On In Daytime
<option>Erratic Operating Times
<option>Flashing/Flickering
<option>Causing Tv/Radio Interference
<option>Obscured By Hedge/Tree Branches
<option>Bracket Arm Needs Realigning
<option>Shade/Cover Missing
<option>Column In Poor Condition
<option>Several Lights Out (please state how many)
<option>Column Leaning
<option>Door Missing/Wires Exposed
<option>Column Knocked Down/Traffic Accident
<option>Lantern Or Bracket Broken Off/Hanging On Wires
<option>Shade/Cover Hanging Open
<option>Other
</select>
```

Using Jquery I want to transform this HTML once the document has loaded to this:-
Adding an optgroup after the 11'th option and also adding the closing `</option>` tag

```
<select name="Fault" class="textbox">
<option>Single Light Out</option>
<option>Light Dim</option>
<option>Light On In Daytime</option>
<option>Erratic Operating Times</option>
<option>Flashing/Flickering</option>
<option>Causing Tv/Radio Interference</option>
<option>Obscured By Hedge/Tree Branches</option>
<option>Bracket Arm Needs Realigning</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Missing</option>
<option>Column In Poor Condition</option>
<option>Several Lights Out (please state how many)</option>
    <optgroup label="Urgent Reasons">
<option>Column Leaning</option>
<option>Door Missing/Wires Exposed</option>
<option>Column Knocked Down/Traffic Accident</option>
<option>Lantern Or Bracket Broken Off/Hanging On Wires</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Hanging Open</option>
<option>Other</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `:nth-child(n+7)` you select all children greater than index 7.

```
$('option:nth-child(n+7)').wrapAll('<optgroup  label="Urgent Reasons">');
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/ecS4H/)

The non-closing `<option>` is non-valid HTML so I'm not sure how jQuery handles this, since it just does valid DOM-manipulation. I'm suggest that you fix this non-closing tags before you parse the HTML.

Comment: Actually the HTML spec says the the closing option tag is optional.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the option tags, if you can read the HTML code into a string that would allow you to run a replace. Something like (this is a javascript example since we're talking about jQuery)

```
raw_code.replace(/(<option>.+)/g, "$1</option>\n");
```